# Insertion operation in SqlCe in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I am trying to insert some data into mydatabase but getting error like  "Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(Dic)' because it has no primary key." 
My database name is "condrokotha_new.sdf" and it has a table named "dic" which have 2 columns named "english" and "bangla". I made this database in another C# project in vs 2010. Then i used this database into my windowsphone project. I can show data from database but when i try to insert data i am getting error.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    condrokotha_newContext db = null;


    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        db = new condrokotha_newContext(condrokotha_newContext.ConnectionString);
        db.CreateIfNotExists();
        db.LogDebug = true;

    }

 private void fav_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      add_new_words("cintakhela","ami");

    }


private void add_new_words(string e_word,string b_word)
    {
        using (condrokotha_newContext context = new condrokotha_newContext(condrokotha_newContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            Dic d = new Dic();

            d.English = e_word;
            d.Bangla = b_word;

            context.Dics.InsertOnSubmit(d);

            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
  }
```

My data context code like these :

```
    public static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/condrokotha_new.sdf";

    public static string ConnectionStringReadOnly = "Data Source=appdata:/condrokotha_new.sdf;File Mode=Read Only;";

    public static string FileName = "condrokotha_new.sdf";

    public condrokotha_newContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

  #region Extensibility Method Definitions
  partial void OnCreated();
  #endregion

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Dic> Dics
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Dic>();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dic")]
public partial class Dic
{

    private string _English;

    private string _Bangla;

    public Dic()
    {
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="english", Storage="_English", DbType="NVarChar(1000)")]
    public string English
    {
        get
        {
            return this._English;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._English != value))
            {
                this._English = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="bangla", Storage="_Bangla", DbType="NText", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string Bangla
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Bangla;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Bangla != value))
            {
                this._Bangla = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`
How can i insert my data into my database?? 
Is there anyone who can help in this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have this

```
    SampleDataContextDataContext db = new SampleDataContextDataContext();
Employee emp = new Employee() {
      FirstName = "Experts",
      Lastname = "Comment",
      Address = "rs.emenu@gmail.com"
}
db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(emp);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

The above code will give you same error when u try to insert a new row. The reason  is that LINQ does not provide the facility to insert data into a table without a primary key. At this point you have two options.

1.Create a store procedure and call it from LINQ.

```
SampleDataContextDataContext db = new SampleDataContextDataContext();
db.InsertEmployeeData("Experts","Comment", "rs.emenu@gmail.com");
```

Here  InsertEmployeeData is a a stored procedure, and called it from the code.

2.Create an insert statement and execute using LINQ.

```
SampleDataContextDataContext db = new SampleDataContextDataContext();

string insertStatement = "Insert into Employee values('Experts', 'Comment','rs.emenu@gmail.com')";
db.ExecuteQuery<Employee>(insertStatement);
```

Here insert query is normal sql query and executed using the the LINQ ExecuteQuery method.